# SQL query to filter where all array items in JSONB array meet condition

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-14

I made a similar post before, but deleted it as it had contextual errors.

One of the tables in my database includes a JSONB column which includes an array of JSON objects. It's not dissimilar to this example of a `session` table which I've mocked up below.

| id | user_id | snapshot | inserted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 37 | {cart: [{product_id: 1, price_in_cents: 3000, name: "product A"}, {product_id: 2, price_in_cents: 2500, name: "product B"}]} | 2022-01-01 20:00:00.000000 |
| 2 | 24 | {cart: [{product_id: 1, price_in_cents: 3000, name: "product A"}, {product_id: 3, price_in_cents: 5500, name: "product C"}]} | 2022-01-02 20:00:00.000000 |
| 3 | 88 | {cart: [{product_id: 4, price_in_cents: 1500, name: "product D"}, {product_id: 2, price_in_cents: 2500, name: "product B"}]} | 2022-01-03 20:00:00.000000 |

The query I've worked with to retrieve records from this table is as follows.

```sql
SELECT sessions.*
FROM sessions
INNER JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT *
    FROM jsonb_to_recordset(sessions.snapshot->'cart')
    AS product(
        "product_id" integer,
        "name" varchar,
        "price_in_cents" integer
    )
) AS cart ON true;
```

I've been trying to update the query above to retrieve only the records in the sessions table for which **ALL** of the products in the cart have a `price_in_cents` value of greater than `2000`.

To this point, I've not had any success on forming this query but I'd be grateful if anyone here can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked well for me and allowed me the flexibility to use different comparison operators other than just ones such as `==` or `<=`.

In one of the scenarios I needed to construct, I also needed to have my `WHERE` in the subquery also compare against an array of values using the `IN` comparison operator, which was not viable using some of the other solutions that were looked at.

Leaving this here in case others run into the same issue as I did, or if others find better solutions or want to propose suggestions to build upon this one.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM sessions
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT sessions.*
    FROM sessions
    INNER JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT *
        FROM jsonb_to_recordset(sessions.snapshot->'cart')
        AS product(
            "product_id" integer,
            "name" varchar,
            "price_in_cents" integer
        )
    ) AS cart ON true
    WHERE name ILIKE "Product%";
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON path expression:

```
select *
from sessions
  ...
where not sessions.snapshot @@ '$.cart[*].price_in_cents <= 2000'
```

There is no JSON path expression that would check that all array elements are greater 2000. So this returns those rows where no element is smaller than 2000 - because that can be expressed with a JSON path expression.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution based on the idea of your original query.
Each element of the cart JSON array object is joined to its `sessions` parent row. You 're left adding the WHERE clause conditions now that the wanted JSON array elements are exposed.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    sess.id,
    sess.user_id,
    sess.inserted_at,
    cart_items.cart_name,
    cart_items.cart_product_id,
    cart_items.cart_price_in_cents
  FROM sessions sess,
    LATERAL (SELECT (snapshot -> 'cart') snapshot_cart FROM sessions WHERE id = sess.id) snap_arr,
    LATERAL (SELECT
               (value::jsonb ->> 'name')::text cart_name,
               (value::jsonb -> 'product_id')::int cart_product_id,
               (value::jsonb -> 'price_in_cents')::int cart_price_in_cents
             FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(snap_arr.snapshot_cart)) cart_items
) session_snapshot_cart_product;
```

Explanation :

- From the `sessions` table, the `cart` array is exctracted and joined per `sessions` row
- The necessary items of the `cart` JSON array is then unnested by the second join using the `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(jsonb)` function